# Open file (CTRL+O) opens with no schema in dbeaver

Tags: dbeaver

I'm new to DBeaver and in my project, I have a lot of folders for SQL scripts. I tend to use CTRL+O quite a bit, but the result is that I always lose the schema I was actively working on and need to select it again.

Is there a way for me to make it so that when I already have an active schema in an SQL editor it keeps that as the schema for the opened file?

I need it to open the file so I can edit it as well, not simply run it.